# Rails fastest way to do several query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

In rails 5, I got a array of attribute:

```
array_of_attribute = ["a","b","c","a","c"]
```

I want to find corresponding object in a table

```
objets = Objet.where({"attribute_column": array_of_attribute})
```

but in 'objets', "a" and "c" are only one time.

I can do :

```
objets = array_of_attribute.map{|aoa| Objet.where({"attribute_column": aoa}) }
```

but its perform n queries and I'm afraid of the perform in this case.

What is the fastest way to do this query ?

Is it a fast way to perform this kind of query and get the quantity of each object?

Comment: *"a" and "c" are only one time* You mean to exclude duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Since you say , " 'a' and 'c' are only one time" you can remove the duplicate by using `uniq`. So you can change your command to 
`objets = Objet.where({"attribute_column": array_of_attribute.uniq})`